# 1-D intersection of lines given begin and end points

Tags: python, comparative-review, interval, coordinate-system

I have a fairly basic question here: I want to find if two lines on a 1-D plane intersect. I know of two simple ways to solve this, but I wanted to know if Python has a more elegant way to solve this.

```
x = [1, 10] # 1 = begin, 10 = end
y = [15, 20]
z = [5, 12]

#Method 1: Works. Is quick. Lots of typing.
def is_intersect_1(a, b):
    bool_check = False
    if a[0] <= b[0] <= a[1] or \
    a[0] <= b[1] <= a[1] or \
    b[0] <= a[0] <= b[1] or \
    b[0] <= a[1] <= b[1]:
        bool_check = True
    return bool_check

is_intersect_1(x,y) # False
is_intersect_1(x,z) # True

#Method 2: Quicker to write. Simpler to read. Uses more memory and is slower.

def is_intersect_2(a, b):
    bool_check = False
    if set(range(a[0], a[1]+1)).intersection(set(range(b[0], b[1])):
        bool_check = True
    return bool_check

is_intersect_2(x,y) # False
is_intersect_2(x,z) # True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Using explicit booleans is a common antipattern:

  ```
  check = False
  if condition:
      check = True
  return check
  ```

  is equivalent to much more transparent (and preferable)

  ```
  return condition
  ```
- Segments *do not* intersect if `a` lies completely to the left, or completely to the right of `b`. Assuming that segments are themselves sorted:

  ```
  def is_intersect_3(a, b):
      return not (a[1] < b[0] or a[0] > b[1])
  ```
- `is_intersect_2` fails badly on floats